# Discord bot not logging in (discord.py python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit

So the bot doesn't login as a user on startup, I am using repl.it python and referenced https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-discord-bot-with-python/

This is the code that I am using, please tell me how to fix the problem
Also, if you can, can you tell me how to shorten the big chunks of 'stock0007 = changeStockPrice(stock0007)'?

Is the Chinese the problem?

```
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import time
import random
import logging

client = discord.Client()

print("I am working")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

def get_quote():
  response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  quote = json_data[0]['q'] + " -" + json_data[0]['a']
  return(quote)

stockA = 0.2
stockB = 1.5
stockC = 19.8
stockD = 0.3
stockE = 3.5

stock0007 = 7.8
stock0013 = 1.9
stock0014 = 4.7
stock0024 = 6.1
stock0130 = 5.0
stock0414 = 1.3
stock0999 = 2.6
stock1234 = 4.8
stock1254 = 9.2
stock1314 = 9.6
stock1324 = 6.7
stock2256 = 9.8
stock3434 = 7.2
stock3444 = 11.9
stock4444 = 9.1
stock5454 = 2.2
stock6464 = 3.9
stock6572 = 2.8
stock8787 = 0.2
stock9373 = 8.0
stock9501 = 7.3

stockHAIYAA = 5.6
stockUYB = 1.4
stockRYAN = 9.0
stockMSG = 7.8
stockFATMUEL = 4.5

def get_stocklist():
  response = f"""藍籌股：
1E Discord 股（A） {stockA}
Ms Yeung Happy Maths（B） {stockB}
Ms Yeung Ryan Inc.（C） {stockC}
Mr Lam Homework Inc.（D） {stockD}
Ms Wong Puppy Fun Club（E） {stockE}

紅籌股：
四硬電器（0007） {stock0007}
二壞車行（0013） {stock0013}
友從生果（0014） {stock0014}
染疫醫療（0024） {stock0024}
跳掣燈飾（0130） {stock0130}
漏霉戲爐具（0414） {stock0414}
呃錢集運（0999） {stock0999}
傷蔘中藥（1234） {stock1234}
失菱巴士（1254） {stock1254}
實川口罩（1314） {stock1314}
劫機航空（1324） {stock1324}
室頭石化（2256） {stock2256}
買定人壽（3434） {stock3434}
實輸電競（3444） {stock3444}
博執公司（4444） {stock4444}
死梗移民（5454） {stock5454}
九吾搭八教育（6464） {stock6464}
楚晒補習社（6572） {stock6572}
動森大頭菜（8787） {stock8787}
界堵玻璃（9373） {stock9373}
戴上綠光 (9501)  {stock9501}

外國股：
HAIYAA index {stockHAIYAA}
UYB index {stockUYB}
RYAN index {stockRYAN}
MSG index {stockMSG}
FATMUEL index {stockFATMUEL}
  """
  return(response)

def changeStockPrice(stock):
  stock = stock + random.randint(-10, 10)/10
  return(stock)


#while True:
#  
#  time.sleep(86400)

while True:
  time.sleep(300)
  stockA = changeStockPrice(stockA)
  stockB = changeStockPrice(stockB)
  stockC = changeStockPrice(stockC)
  stockD = changeStockPrice(stockD)
  stockE = changeStockPrice(stockE)
  stock0007 = changeStockPrice(stock0007)
  stock0013 = changeStockPrice(stock0013)
  stock0014 = changeStockPrice(stock0014)
  stock0024 = changeStockPrice(stock0024)
  stock0130 = changeStockPrice(stock0130)
  stock0414 = changeStockPrice(stock0414)
  stock0999 = changeStockPrice(stock0999)
  stock1234 = changeStockPrice(stock1234)
  stock1254 = changeStockPrice(stock1254)
  stock1314 = changeStockPrice(stock1314)
  stock1324 = changeStockPrice(stock1324)
  stock2256 = changeStockPrice(stock2256)
  stock3434 = changeStockPrice(stock3434)
  stock3444 = changeStockPrice(stock3444)
  stock4444 = changeStockPrice(stock4444)
  stock5454 = changeStockPrice(stock5454)
  stock6464 = changeStockPrice(stock6464)
  stock6572 = changeStockPrice(stock6572)
  stock8787 = changeStockPrice(stock8787)
  stock9373 = changeStockPrice(stock9373)
  stock9501 = changeStockPrice(stock9501)

async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$stocks'):
    stocklist = get_stocklist()
    await message.channel.send(stocklist)

keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't login"? What's the output in the console? Why are you assuming it's not logging in? In how many guild's the bot is in?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński the bot is not online, and it does not respond to any commands. `@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client)` does not occur as well.
There is no output (except for the `print("I am working")`) and the bot is only in a test server I have.

Comment: While True and Discord.py aren't friends, you should find another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite while loop, so `client.run()` is never reached, so your bot is never started.

```py
while True:
    time.sleep(300)
    stock...
```